# Categories from 2 ComboBox affecting third Combobox for datagridview with SQL

Tags: c#, sql, search, datagridview, combobox

To put it into short story

i wanted something like "SELECT companyName FROM table where mainCategory = firstcombobox and subcategory = secondcombobox" , how do i do the sql query?

==========================
Long story

I have created a form , with a working coding , but i need an extra assistance.

Somewhat , i am stuck on trying to figure out how to let the 3rd combobox value , determined by the first and second.

and what i wanted is , something like , getting the value of Main Category and Sub category to effect the list of the third combo box.

i just need the SQL query , such as : "SELECT companyName FROM table where maincategory = firstcombobox and subcategory = secondcombobox"

and then shows the company name within the picks of main and sub category.

Like this :

[image: Main Form]

For the Main Category and Sub-Category , i have it working with this code.
This code also includes the 3rd ComboBox code which right now operates without the first and second combobox attached to the 3rd combobox code.

```
public partial class User : Form
    {

        Dictionary<string, List<string>> Category = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        DataSet ds1;

        public User()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void User_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
            conn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter daMain = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MAINCATE", conn);
            ds1 = new DataSet();

            daMain.Fill(ds1, "Maincate");

            DataTable dt = ds1.Tables["MAINCATE"];
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                List<string> SubCats = new List<string> 
                {
                 dr["Subcat1"].ToString(), 
                 dr["Subcat2"].ToString(),
                 dr["Subcat3"].ToString(),
                 dr["Subcat4"].ToString()
                };
                Category.Add(dr["mainCate"].ToString(), SubCats);
                mainCatU.Items.Add(dr["mainCate"].ToString());
            }

            mainCatU.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            mainCatU.Enabled = true;
            subCatU.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

//**Code for third combobox**

            SqlDataAdapter daSearch = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT cName FROM ComDet", conn);
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            ListU.DataSource = dt1;
            daSearch.Fill(dt1);
            ListU.ValueMember = "cName";
            ListU.DisplayMember = "cName";
            ListU.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            ListU.Enabled = true;

//**----------------------**

            conn.Close();   
        }

        private void mainCatU_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Category.ContainsKey(mainCatU.SelectedItem.ToString()))
            {
                subCatU.DataSource = Category[mainCatU.SelectedItem.ToString()];
            }
        }
```

and the databases are as shown :

dbo.MAINCATE
[image: MAINCATE]

dbo.ComDet
[image: ComDet]

and the code for the `View Selected Company` `button` is :

```
private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
            conn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter daS = new SqlDataAdapter("select cName, cDetails, cDetails2 from ComDet where cName = @cName", conn);
            daS.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@cName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ListU.SelectedValue;

            DataTable dts3 = new DataTable();
            daS.Fill(dts3);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dts3.DefaultView;
            dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

            conn.Close();

        }
```

- again , right now the third combo box is coded  to run without the maincategory and subcategory

========================

Answered - Created a button called search , and took the coding from form load into the button , added with SQLCon , and added the SQLQuery needed..

Thx guys.. :)

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
            conn.Open();

            string myRequest = "SELECT cName FROM ComDet where mainCate = '" + mainCatU.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and Subcat = '" + subCatU.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";

            SqlDataAdapter daSearch = new SqlDataAdapter(myRequest, conn);
            DataTable dtSea = new DataTable();
            ListU.DataSource = dtSea;
            daSearch.Fill(dtSea);
            ListU.ValueMember = "cName";
            ListU.DisplayMember = "cName";
            ListU.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            ListU.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Can someone really help this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling following function on `SelectedValue` change event of `mainCatU` and `subCatU` combo:

```
private void SetCompanyList()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(mainCatU.SelectedValue)) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(subCatU.SelectedValue))) return;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
    conn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter daMain = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT cName FROM ComDet where mainCate = @mainCat subCat = @subCate", conn);
    daMain.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@mainCat", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = mainCatU.SelectedValue;
    daMain.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@subCate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = subCatU.SelectedValue;

    DataTable _table = new DataTable();

    daMain.Fill(_table);

    ListU.DataSource = _table;
}
```

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin Check it and let me know in case of any error.

Comment: i've added my answer.. its in my edited post above.. down below..

but i've tried your codes anyway..

changed a few parts here and there , and it worked.. :)

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin Ok, If u think my suggested solution worth for solving ur problem then u must mark my suggeted solution as answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use by the following query:

```
     SELECT companyName FROM table where mainCategory = '" + mainCatU.selectedValue +     "'       and subcategory = '" + subCatU.selectedValue + "'"
```

Comment: thx.. but i used string myRequest = "SELECT cName FROM ComDet where mainCate = '" + mainCatU.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and Subcat = '" + subCatU.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'"; instead. :)