# SQL Queries from 2 ComboBox determining third combobox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, combobox

I have 3 comboBox..

And I wanted a code for the thirdcombobox , something like

`SELECT companyName FROM table where mainCategory = firstcombobox and subcategory = secondcombobox` , how do I do the SQL query?

My main category combobox is called `mainCatU` , and the subcategory is `subCatU`

I managed to make `subCatU`'s value based on `mainCatU` , now I wanted a third combobox value determined by both the value of the maincategory and subcategory.

It is either just an SQL Query or other thing?

Can anyone help?

I have tried following some other codes such as

```
string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Purchase where ItemID=(SELECT ItemID FROM ItemMaster where ItemName='" +  DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text + '" and CategoryID=(SELECT CategoryID FROM ItemMaster where ItemName='"+ DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text + '")";
```

But I do not use that.. Since I am using it like this..

```
SqlDataAdapter daSearch = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT companyName FROM CompanyDetail", conn);
```

Help please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the context? WPF application?

If your tested request is ok, just use the string inside the way "you use like":

```
string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Purchase where ItemID=(SELECT ItemID FROM ItemMaster where ItemName='" +  DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text + "' and CategoryID=(SELECT CategoryID FROM ItemMaster where ItemName='" + DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text + "')";
SqlDataAdapter daSearch = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);
```

You also made mistakes with the " and ' in your previous version.

For a better response, please update your question with:
- info about your whole solution (type of application, environment)
- info about your datamodel, because your request does not seem to be well written

**EDIT 1 after your comments:**

your problem is that you don't know how to get the value of the selected item in your comboBox. See here for difference between SelectedItem, SelectedValue...
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2006/11/07/combobox-selecteditem-selectedvalue-selectedwhat.aspx?Redirected=true

Once you will be ready to read these values, create your query in a string like this

```
string myRequest = "SELECT companyName FROM table where mainCategory = '" + *value of mainCatU* + "' and subcategory = '" + *value of subCatU* + "'";
```

Then pass the string to SQL and get the results:
SqlDataAdapter daSearch = new SqlDataAdapter(myRequest, conn);

Comment: ah.. but then im using combobox , the dropdownlist was someone elses'..

i'll update it.. :) in a minute

Comment: also .. for combobox... 

example - my first combobox named mainCatU , so if i put it mainCatU.SelectedItem.Text ... the 'text' does not exist.. i only have SelectedItem.ToString , Equals and GetHype and GetHashCode

Comment: Please describe the type of project you are doing: comboBox in WPF and combobox in WinForms are not the same and do not have the same properties

Comment: if u need full details , i have actually setup a question before this , its the same thing , but different title..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779276/categories-from-2-combobox-affecting-third-combobox-for-datagridview-with-sql

Comment: Considering your question is only about the SQL request, use mainCatU.SelectedItem.ToString() and subCatU.SelectedItem.ToString() in my request edited previously to get the company names.

Be careful when using those values: you should check if both comboboxes have selected values before calling this line (I don't know where you want to call this line)

Comment: should i change the event for mainCatU_SelectedIndexChanged ?

Comment: the code kinda works.. but the 3rd combo box did not show anything.. *no errors though.. *

Comment: i tried putting the code into a button , called search , and i got handler error at da.fill

Comment: nvm.. i got it to work.. i had the wrong table name and wrong column name.. THX! :D

Comment: Cool! For the event where you should do this, it should be on the 2nd combo yes. In fact if the choice is sequential (that is to say you HAVE to select an item on the 1st combo then it updates the 2nd one and then you HAVE to select an item on the 2nd one to select the 3rd) I would put some enable/disable logic on the combos: i would enable the 3rd one only after a selection on the 2nd one for example.

Comment: i actually put it into a button instead , so that the code wouldnt generate an error when there's no matches of data for 3rd combobox..